# Find the splitting fields of the polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ideals, group-isomorphism

What are the splitting fields for the polynomials

$f(x)=x^4 + 5x^2 +4 $

and

$f(x)=x^4 - x^2 - 2 $

I know that any polynomial has a splitting field and by using the proof of this fact  $f(x)$ of degree $n$ with roots $c_1....c_k$ can be written as $f(x)=(x-c_1)...(x-c_k)g(x)$ where $g(x)$ has no roots in F. Then factor g(x) into irreducible polynomials, choose one, and pass to the field where F[x]/ and then keep repeating, but I am having a very hard time actually implementing. I know the general idea but can't seem to put it into practice.

Comment: What's your base field?  $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: F[x] usually refers to the ring of polynomials in F...which is a ring, not a field.  Unless you mean the quotient field rational polynomials....but that seems odd

Comment: Sorry I meant for f(x) in F

Comment: so yes I assume rational numbers

Answer (score 5):

(1) $0=x^4+5x^2+4=(x^2+1)(x^2+4)\Rightarrow x= \pm i, \pm 2i.$ So the splitting field of this polynomial is $\mathbb Q(i).$

(2). $0=x^4-x^2-2=(x^2+1)(x^2-2) \Rightarrow x= \pm i, \pm \sqrt 2.$ So the splitting field of this polynomial is $\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt 2).$

*Note:* To find the splitting field of a given polynomial over $\mathbb Q,$ first consider it as a polynomial over $\mathbb C.$ Since $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed, the polynomial will splits into linear factors. Now *"add"* the roots of the polynomial to $\mathbb Q.$ You can easily show that the resulting field is the splitting field of the given polynomial.

Comment: Of course, splitting the polynomial is usually not as easy as it was for these two.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I completely agree with you. The last part of my answer (*"Note"*) is mainly theoretical. For polynomials of degree $n \geq 5$ no general method exists.